# Javascript array classify depending on number

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a simple array

```
const users = []
```

It's array of user, i want that for my 10 users attribute a category to have same number of users with category 1, same of users with category 3 ...

For n users i want to push a category number value depending on count of category

```
const usersCount = 10
const category = 5
for(let i = 0; i<= usersCount; i++){
  // classify users
}
```

In output i want to have when users = 5 :

```
users = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
```

The category for first users will be 1 and for last will be 5

In output i want to have when users = 3 :

```
users = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
```

In output i want to have when category = 2 :

```
users = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```

In output i want to have when category = 6 :

```
users = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

Comment: can you describe the logic?

Comment: not enough, we need more output examples.

Comment: Sorry i fix one example and i add one more

Comment: I want to classify array of user depending on number of category

Comment: You've described an algorithmic problem (sort of :-) ), but you haven't shown your attempt to solve it or told us where specifically you're stuck. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I had more explaination on what i attempt

Comment: Can you post some code? even pseudo code? As TJ said, a [mcve] would be great.

Comment: It's my problem, i know only input and output and it's difficult to push some code

Comment: @LionelB Try it. If you can write in english, you can express an algorithm, even a wrong one. Feel free to use pseudo-code. I shared an answer because I am not a fan of the other one. You can still ignore them and try to write yours first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is genuine, but please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As a junior, you wont learn much by copy pasting code without trying to write it first.

```javascript
const usersCount = 10

const f = category => [...Array(usersCount)].map((_,i) => (i / category | 0) + 1)

console.log(f(2))
console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(4))
console.log(f(5))
console.log(f(6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczNCsIwEATge59ij7uosfXvVkF8DBEJMS2Rmi2bVCj47lHpoWCO8zEzD/3SwYjr48rz3aZk2IcIQ7ASzjz4CDVUZVFM3HyT0dG2LCPUR7gopU4iesR5QFf11D3ibeno10EH63n0hpJgARVNl9xZ1XGLDW6I/mSbyS6TfSYHopQ@)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doSomething(n){
  const el = 10;
  let res = [];
  let h = 1;
  for(let i = 1; i<= el; i++){
    res.push(h);
    if(i%n === 0){
      h++;
    }
    
  }
  console.log(res.toString());
}
doSomething(2);
doSomething(3);
doSomething(4);
doSomething(5);
doSomething(6);
```